# Stream video, using vlc, to android

Tags: android, video-streaming, vlc, transcoding

I start the server like this:

```
vlc --ttl 12 -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password something --rtsp-host localhost:5544
```

Then I telnet to the server and execute the following:

```
new test vod
setup test output #transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=256,fps=20,scale=0,width=320,height=180,acodec=mp3,ab=64,channels=1,samplerate=22050}
setup test input "/home/snot/Desktop/stream/Abby Main.wmv"
setup test enabled
```

I can't seem to find the proper transcoding parameters since no matter which I input the device won't play the video.

Personally I'm using android 4.0.3 but I'd like it to work for version 2.3.3 and possible lower as well. But right now I'll be happy for something just working on some version.

Any help appreciated,

Seb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very important that the video be encoded with the h264 settings that are collectively known as the "baseline profile". Android really hates b-frames.

I use this:

## transcode{vcodec=h264,width=320,vb=110,venc=x264{keyint=5,vbv-bufsize=250,vbv-maxrate=110,partitions=all,level=3.1,ratetol=0.1, bframes=0},acodec=mp4a,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100,deinterlace,audio-sync}");

^^ I think that has most of the settings from baseline profile that android likes (works for me) or you can try using the actual profile.